# Alternative to With statement in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this sql query

```
WITH Stocktype AS (SELECT SUBSTRING([T2_LOOK].[KEY],4,6) AS StkType, T2_LOOK.F1 AS MasterStocktype
FROM T2_LOOK
WHERE Left([T2_LOOK].[KEY],3)='CAT'),
SELECT  *                           
FROM ((T2_BRA INNER JOIN T2_HEAD ON T2_BRA.REF = T2_HEAD.REF)  INNER JOIN Stocktype ON T2_HEAD.SUPPLIER = Stocktype .SuppCode)
```

I need this query to work in ms access, I know in ms access you can't use the statement WITH, does anyone know an alternative or how I would get this to work in access? Thanks in advance

Comment: `WITH` are essentially shorthand for subqueries for more readable SQL statements especially if used more than once.

Answer (score 2):

You can just replace it as a subquery:

```
SELECT  *                           
FROM (T2_BRA INNER JOIN
      T2_HEAD
      ON T2_BRA.REF = T2_HEAD.REF
     ) INNER JOIN
     (SELECT MID([T2_LOOK].[KEY], 4, 6) AS StkType,
             T2_LOOK.F1 AS MasterStocktype
      FROM T2_LOOK
      WHERE Left([T2_LOOK].[KEY], 3) = "CAT"
     ) as Stocktype
     ON T2_HEAD.SUPPLIER = Stocktype.SuppCode;
```

Of course, this still will not work (even with the fixes for MS Access syntax) because `Stocktype` doesn't have a column called `SuppCode`.  However, that is an issue with your original query, so it is not clear how to fix it.

Comment: I stripped the query down a lot, this is a typo made by me on the column name but your solution works! Thanks :)